# How to delete all files and sub-folders in a folder except for 1 folder in a .bat script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder that stores many log files and sub-folders. I would like to delete all files and sub-folders except 1 folder, named Excel_Export, which should not be deleted. I am using the following commands in my batch script:

```
move D:\ABC\Delete_Test\Retain_Folder D:\ABC
rd /s /q "D:\ABC\Delete_Test"
move D:\ABC\Retain_Folder D:\ABC\Delete_Test
```

However, after this script runs, even the 'Retain_Folder' is getting deleted except for the files inside it. What is it that I am doing wrong in the above command?
Also, is there a better way to do it?

NOTE:
All the other folders' names (that are to be deleted) starts with the '$' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested - it deletes all normal files in `d:\abc` and then removes all folders beginning with `$` in the same folder.

```
@echo off
del "d:\abc\*.*?"
for /d %%a in ("d:\abc\$*") do rd /s /q "%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is probably the most efficient (fastest) way to accomplish your task, except you have one small bug. Your `RD` command removes the `Delete_Test` folder, so you must recreate it before you can move `Retain_Folder` back to where it belongs. You also probably want to redirect output to null when you `move` the folder - you don't need to see the move message.

```
move "D:\ABC\Delete_Test\Retain_Folder" "D:\ABC" >nul
rd /s /q "D:\ABC\Delete_Test"
md "D:\ABC\Delete_Test"
move "D:\ABC\Retain_Folder" "D:\ABC\Delete_Test" >nul
```

This strategy only works properly if you know that `D:\ABC\Retain_Folder` does not already exist before you start, or if it does exist, then it must be empty.